# How can I create a new variable that is based on a relational column in Stata?

Tags: stata

My dataset is panel data in the long format with the columns: id, var1, syear, partner_id

var1 is the value of interest related to a person with the respective id

partner_id is the ID of the partner (e.g. wife or husband) of a person defined by id

Now I want to create a new variable var2 that takes the values (from var1) of the partner of the person for each id & year.

When using the suggested code below for non-panel data (thx to @Nick-Cox)
var2 turns out as the following:

[image]

But how I need it to be is like:

[image]

Since I do not have any prior experience Stata, I would appreciate your help!

So here is the simplified data as code (If that is important: In my original dataset there are more years and sometimes different partners over the years as well as missings; e.g. when there is a year without a partner):

```
id syear var1 partner_id
1 2000 1000 2 
1 2001 2000 2
2 2000 3000 1
2 2001 4000 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this rendering of your first-posted data and problem (noting that presenting data as images is less helpful than presenting data as code):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(id var1 partner_id var2)
1  5000 4  3000
2  2000 1  5000
3  1000 5 10000
4  3000 2  2000
5 10000 3  1000
end

gen wanted = var1[partner_id]

assert wanted == var2
```

EDIT  Consider now this solution for your revised data. The revised data example is probably deceptively simple with just two identifiers which are each other's partners, for which trivial code would suffice. However, I have written rather more general code.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input byte id int syear float var1 byte partner_id
1 2000 1000 2
1 2001 2000 2
2 2000 3000 1
2 2001 4000 1
end

save orig, replace 

keep id var1 syear 
rename (id var1) (partner_id wanted)
merge 1:1 partner_id syear using orig

sort id syear 

list 

     +-----------------------------------------------------+
     | partne~d   syear   wanted   id   var1        _merge |
     |-----------------------------------------------------|
  1. |        2    2000     3000    1   1000   matched (3) |
  2. |        2    2001     4000    1   2000   matched (3) |
  3. |        1    2000     1000    2   3000   matched (3) |
  4. |        1    2001     2000    2   4000   matched (3) |
     +-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: That makes so much sense, thank you!!! 
One last question: you probably mean: 
`rename (id partner_id) (var1 wanted)` (?)

Comment: No; I meant what I wrote.